# Public List In MainActivity and MVVM

Tags: mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-mvvm

I need some help with MVVM architecture.
I have a RecyclerView that receives LiveData and display it perfectly, however, my recyclerView requires another source of Data to customize colors and backgrounds of TextViews. for now I'm using a public list declared in the Mainactivity, But I've read that it's not a good practice.
is it possible to perform a non-live request to database from inside RecyclerView, in order to replace the public list ? if not I would really like some suggestions.

here is my onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultRecyclerViewAdapter.ResultHolder holder, int position) {
       
        Results currentResult = results.get(position);
        
        holder.ston1.setText(currentResult.getSton1());
        holder.ston2.setText(String.valueOf(currentResult.getSton2()));

        holder.ston1.setBackgroundColor(0xFF12FF45);
        holder.ston2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF12FF45);

        holder.ston1.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
        holder.ston2.getBackground().setAlpha(100);

        for (Ston ston: MainActivity.Stons){
            if (currentResult.getStonCode().equals(ston.getStonCode()) && currentResult.getStonType().equals(ston.getStonType())){

                switch (ston.getStonSelected()) {
                    case "WADS":
                        holder.ston1.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                        break;
                    case "WQAS":
                        holder.ston2.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }


    holder.ston1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Boolean found = false;
            for (Ston ston: MainActivity.Stons){
                if (currentResult.getStonCode().equals(ston.getStonCode())){
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                holder.ston1.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                MainActivity.Stons.add(new Stons(currentResult.getStonCode(),"WADS",
                        currentResult.getStonType()));
            } 
            else {
                for (Ston ston : MainActivity.Stons) {
                    if (currentResult.getStonCode().equals(ston.getStonCode()) && ston.getStonSelected().equals("WADS") && 
                        ston.getStonType().equals(currentResult.getStonType())){
                        MainActivity.Stons.remove(ston);
                        holder.ston1.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });

    holder.ston2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Boolean found = false;
            for (Ston ston: MainActivity.Stons){
                if (currentResult.getStonCode().equals(ston.getStonCode())){
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                holder.ston2.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                MainActivity.Stons.add(new Stons(currentResult.getStonCode(),"WQAS",
                        currentResult.getStonType()));
            } 
            else {
                for (Ston ston : MainActivity.Stons) {
                    if (currentResult.getStonCode().equals(ston.getStonCode()) && ston.getStonSelected().equals("WQAS") && 
                        ston.getStonType().equals(currentResult.getStonType())){
                        MainActivity.Stons.remove(ston);
                        holder.ston2.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any help here please :) , Should I add more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that I see is to create new type specifically for your recyclerview adapter that will hold both Results object and information that you use for background alpha. So in your activity (or fragment) when livedata observer is triggered you don't directly pass it to adapter, but first create collection of objects of your new type, and then pass it to adapter. And I strongly suggest you to use Kotlin if possible, there you can use collection mapping to map collection from the db to your new type's collection.

Comment: Thank you , it is too late for me to switch to Kotlin. I managed to query db from inside adapter but I'm still not satisfied with it

Comment: @dxtr how can it be late?:) You can easily use them together (java and kotlin).

Comment: Oh I should read about that , I never imagined they can be used together. Thanks a lot